# Can't Access Super Globals Inside __callStatic?

Tags: php, static-methods

The following code fails on my install of `PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.2` which makes me wonder why I can't access the $_SERVER Super Global inside this method.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$method = '_SERVER';
var_dump($$method); // Works fine

class i
{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $method = '_SERVER';
        var_dump($$method); // Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER
    }
}

i::method();
```

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: both dont work for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AdKi1h

Comment: @Gordon, That codepad probably runs over the CLI which is why `$_SERVER` is empty.

Comment: nope: http://codepad.viper-7.com/R1J5SK

Comment: @Gordon, I see they have [5.3.9-dev](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ezEfO8) so perhaps I found a PHP bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated in the manual:

```
Note: Variable variables

Superglobals cannot be used as variable variables inside functions or class methods.
```

([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php))

Comment: and there it is.  man, I learn something new every day. :) well done. +1

Answer (score 2):

[edit - added a possible workaround]

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

class i
{
    public static function __callStatic( $method, $args)
    {
        switch( $method )
        {
        case 'GLOBALS':
            $var =& $GLOBALS;
            break;

        case '_SERVER':
            $var =& $_SERVER;
            break;

        case '_GET':
            $var =& $_GET;
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            throw new Exception( 'Undefined variable.' );

        }

        var_dump( $var );
    }
}

i::_SERVER();
i::_GET();
```

[original answer]
This is weird.  I agree that it may be a PHP bug.  However, the superglobal does work, just not as a variable variable.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$method = '_SERVER';
var_dump($$method); // Works fine

class i
{
    public static function __callStatic( $method, $args)
    {
        var_dump( $_SERVER ); // works

        var_dump( $$method ); // Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER
    }
}

i::_SERVER();
```

Comment: Want even more weirdness... the "this works" line does not work on my server with 5.3.1. Not only that, `$GLOBALS['_SERVER']` is null on my server.